# MAX with group by by 2 columns

Tags: postgresql, group-by, max

I have a query

```
create table film_actor (
    actor_id integer,
    film_id integer);
create table film (
    film_id integer,
    title varchar);
create table actor (
    actor_id integer,
    first_name varchar,
    last_name varchar);

INSERT INTO film_actor (actor_id, film_id) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO film_actor (actor_id, film_id) VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO film_actor (actor_id, film_id) VALUES (1, 3);
INSERT INTO film_actor (actor_id, film_id) VALUES (2, 1);
INSERT INTO film_actor (actor_id, film_id) VALUES (2, 2);
INSERT INTO film_actor (actor_id, film_id) VALUES (2, 3);
INSERT INTO film_actor (actor_id, film_id) VALUES (3, 1);
INSERT INTO film (film_id, title) VALUES (1, 'First');
INSERT INTO film (film_id, title) VALUES (2, 'Second');
INSERT INTO film (film_id, title) VALUES (3, 'Third');
INSERT INTO film (film_id, title) VALUES (4, 'Fourth');
INSERT INTO actor (actor_id, first_name, last_name) VALUES (1, 'John', 'Snow');
INSERT INTO actor (actor_id, first_name, last_name) VALUES (2, 'Spider', 'Man');
INSERT INTO actor (actor_id, first_name, last_name) VALUES (3, 'Mike', 'Kameron');
```

```
select max(actors_comparing.counta)
from (
  SELECT fa1.actor_id first_actor, fa2.actor_id second_actor, count(*) counta
  FROM film_actor fa1
  join film_actor fa2
  using (film_id)
  where fa1.actor_id != fa2.actor_id
  group by (fa1.actor_id, fa2.actor_id)
) actors_comparing;
```

I need to add information about pair (fa1.actor_id, fa2.actor_id), but I don't know how.

And I always get error like `must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

I need something like

```
select actors_comparing.first_actor, actors_comparing.second_actor, max(actors_comparing.counta)
from (
  SELECT fa1.actor_id first_actor, fa2.actor_id second_actor, count(*) counta
  FROM film_actor fa1
  join film_actor fa2
  using (film_id)
  where fa1.actor_id != fa2.actor_id
  group by (fa1.actor_id, fa2.actor_id)
) actors_comparing
```

Comment: Please show some example data and the desired result.

Comment: @CL. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/r2Y9CpH8n7MHTeBaqEHe9S/0  I need output like
first_actor_id, second_actor_id, max(actors_comparing.counta)

Comment: To edit your post, click "edit". Please show the desired result.